# Can't work out navbar in bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I can't work out why my navbar button in the top right of my website http://www.fishtrends.com

It works for another site http://www.fishtrends.com/main.html but i'm completely lost as to why it dosn't work for the below code.

code as follows;

```html
<div class = "navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
    <div class="container">
        <a href = "#" class = "navbar-brand"><b>Fishtrends</b> - Social Fish trending</a>
        <button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse"
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <div class= "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">
        <ul class = "nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class = "active"><a href ="/register.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i> Register</li>
          <li class = "dropdown">
            <a href = "#" class = "dropdown-toggle" data-toggle = "dropdown"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></i> Login<b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class = "dropdown-menu" style="padding: 15px; padding-bottom: 0px;">
                <form action="login.php" method="post"> Username:<br /> 
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $submitted_username; ?>" /> 
                    <br /><br /> Password:<br /> <input type="password" name="password" value="" /> 
                    <br /><br /> 

                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Login" /> 
            </form> 
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You should check your code again, there are `<ul>` open without the clse tag `</ul>`. You are using an `<ul>` without `<li>` etc.. before and after the `<form>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not closing a tag properly.

`<button class = "navbar-toggle" data-toggle = "collapse" data-target = ".navHeaderCollapse"`

needs to be closed.

Thats not the only issue. There are more. It's all syntax related though.

Check the markup with W3C's [markup checker](http://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input)

Answer (score 0):

Firt off, make sure the attributes, their respective values and the '=' have no spaces between them, like so: href="style.css"

edit: Also, using an ul without li is pointless, use  instead. Try that and tell what happens.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand...what does the UL/LI statement mean? What should I use instead?